# How to count specific substrings in json

Tags: php, json, count, coordinates, substring

My json string:

```
{
  "nearby_drivers": [
    {
      "drivers": [
        {
          "locations": [
            {
              "lat": 38.670808,
              "lng": -121.49624
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "locations": [
            {
              "lat": 38.625728,
              "lng": -121.514559
            },
          ]
        }
      ],
      "ride_type": "lyft"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get a total count for the (lat, lng) pairs in php. I've had success in counting 1 lat or 1 lng. But i'm not sure on how to do both. Can it be done? Thank you for your time.

Comment: first convert it to an object with json_decode, then array_filter or array_reduce would do the trick.

Comment: Please provide your expected output for your posted sample input.  If there are any fringe cases to consider, please add those sample inputs and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say keep it simple and just do a string count without any type conversions:

```
$input='{
  "nearby_drivers": [
    {
      "drivers": [
        {
          "locations": [
            {
              "lat": 38.670808,
              "lng": -121.49624
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "locations": [
            {
              "lat": 38.625728,
              "lng": -121.514559
            },
          ]
        }
      ],
      "ride_type": "lyft"
    }
  ]
}';

echo "lat count = ",substr_count($input,'"lat"'),"<br>";
echo "lng count = ",substr_count($input,'"lng"');
```

Output:

```
lat count = 2
lng count = 2
```

Comment: Then again if you need to literally count the pairs (like one of those could be standing alone), that could be achieved with regex.